# Responsive Image Resize

Tags: html, css

I have the css Code like this for width less than 479px

```
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 479px) {
  .pi-hidden-2xsx-only {
   max-width: 5px;
   max-height: 5px;
}
```

and my image source use the class like this

```
<a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="" class="pi-hidden-2xsx-only"></a>
```

Why it doesn't work when i applied this class in my image source? when my mobile device is less than the width, my image should be auto resize to fit the rules i applied.

Comment: Is this a simple typo that you forgot to add the correct closing tags? In your example you need one more `}` at the end of your css. And also your media query is set to work at 320px - 479px, not under 320px.

Comment: Are you closing your media query? With "}"

Answer (score 1):

> I have the css Code like this for width less than 320px

The media query should be:

```
@media (max-width: 320px) {
    .pi-hidden-2xsx-only{
      /* your css */
    }
}
```

Comment: i changed but it still didnt change my image size

Answer (score 0):

Try giving code like this

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
    img.pi-hidden-2xsx-only {
        max-width: 5px;
        max-height: 5px;
    }
}
```

or

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
    img.pi-hidden-2xsx-only {
        max-width: 5px;
        max-height: 5px;
    }
}
```

and trying changing `max-width` and `max-height` to `width` and `height`

Answer (score -1):

this is probably because you are writing your class in the css file in a wrong way ...

correct way is to use the tagname `(img)` before the class name like

```
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 479px) {
  img.pi-hidden-2xsx-only {
  max-width: 5px;
  max-height: 5px;
}
```

only change `pi-hidden-2xsx-only.img` to `img.pi-hidden-2xsx-only`

Comment: that's not right. Only class name is suffice to select.

Comment: you cannot add a class name and write tag name after that.
and yes only class name suffice to select. but you are writting it the wrong way

Comment: he didn't write tag name after class name. his selector is just fine already

Comment: If you write img tag before the class you're just specifying that the class must be in an img tag, but in this case, as these people say, the class name will suffice.